# Возможно ли с помощью PHP получить содержимое страницы, которая сгенерена JS?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Задача периодически тырить динамический контент с чужого сайта. Проблема в том, что контент генерится javascript'ом. Пока из потенциальных решений J4P5. Может есть другой способ? И поможет ли в моём случае J4P5?

Comment: логично предположить, что этот javascript не берет данные с воздуха, а они где то хранятся. Вполне возможно, что они запрашиваются по ajax, а это может сильно упростить задачу.

Comment: увы, ajax'а там нет... в header есть подключение нескольких js-файлов, судя по названиям минифицированных и слитых в один. На месте таблицы, стоит вызов скрипта, который её генерит.

Comment: в этом случае можно использовать Node.js или rhino  и выполнить этот js. Возможно, его нужно будет допилить.

Comment: @KoVadim Сайт-то чужой. А если на нём реализация поменяется? Надёжнее будет использовать Selenium или альтернативу, чтобы эмулировать то, как страничка генерируется в браузере.

Comment: да, я это понимаю, к сожалению от меня ждут чудес, т.е. чтобы кодяра всё делала, а заказчик ничего не делал... попробую убедить)

Comment: @ДмитрийШевченко " А если на нём реализация поменяется?" -  вывод на страницу также могут поменять:) и визуально не отличишь:)

Comment: @MoRDa А что вы собираетесь дальше делать с полученным контентом?

Comment: @KoVadim подправить разборку контента, думаю, в 99% случаев будет проще, чем заново разбираться в новом JavaScript'е.

Comment: да, пожалуй, вы всё-таки правы... спасибо за помощь... буду юзать селениум или что-нибудь похожее...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [**Selenium**](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) + [**php-webdriver**](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/), загрузите нужную вам страницу, и затем получите её содержимое при помощи следующего кода:

```
$this->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::tagName('html'))->getText()
```